# Unix - how to merge filename inside content with cat and baseline?

Tags: unix, cat

I want to a merge files (one line) with filename at the begining of the line.

'cat' does a merge on files and  'basename -a' gives filemanes but I don't know how to get both ?

```
$ echo "content1" > f1.txt
$ echo "content2" > f2.txt
$ cat f*.txt > all.txt

$ cat all.txt
content1
content2

$ basename -a f*.txt
f1.txt
f2.txt

Would like this result :
$ cat all.txt
f1.txt  content1
f2.txt  content2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop. Iterate over every `*.txt` file, echo its name to the output file without a newline (done with `echo -n`,) append its contents to the output file, and finally append a newline. Note that `>>` appends. Using `>` would overwrite.

```
rm -f all.txt
for f in *.txt; do echo -n "$f " >> all.txt; cat "$f" >> all.txt; echo >> all.txt; done
```

If your input files already contain a newline at the end, then you skip the final `echo` and just do:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo -n "$f " >> all.txt; cat "$f" >> all.txt; done
```

If you're using tcsh instead of bash, then you can use `foreach`, but you can't write the whole loop in a single command. Normally you would write this in a script:

```
foreach f (*.txt)
    echo -n "$f " >> all.txt
    cat "$f" >> all.txt
end
```

To get this in a single command line you need something like this instead:

```
printf 'foreach f (*.txt)\n echo -n "$f " >> all.txt\n cat "$f" >> all.txt\n end' | tcsh
```

Comment: not working on shell :       $ for f in *.txt ; do echo -n "$f " >> all.txt ; cat "$f" >> all.txt ; done
for: Command not found.
f: Undefined variable.

Comment: @DenisfromValThorens What shell are you using?

Comment: terminal on macOS.

Comment: Well, default shell is tcsh on my terminal . When I switch to bash well working. Tcsh  not supporting loops.... Thanks.

Comment: @DenisfromValThorens Added tcsh version too.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `grep -H`.  Post process to change the delimiter:

```
$ for i in 1 2; do echo content$i > f$i.txt; done
$ grep -H . *.txt 
f1.txt:content1
f2.txt:content2
$ grep -H . *.txt  | sed 's/:/  /'
f1.txt  content1
f2.txt  content2
```

or,

```
$ awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n", FILENAME, $0}' *.txt
f1.txt  content1
f2.txt  content2
```

Comment: Note that I'm using `sed` to replace the `:` instead of `tr` to avoid replacing colons after the first, but this is a pretty pointless attempt at robustness since it will replace the first colon in the filename if one appears.